# How to delete Samba and Kerberos data to start everything from scratch?

Tags: samba, kerberos

I'm doing some experiments with Samba and Kerberos on Ubuntu Server Cuttlefish, by installing `samba`, `krb5-config`, and `winbind`. When installing Kerberos in interactive mode, it asked some questions to automatically config some settings:

```
 +------------------+ Configuring Kerberos Authentication +------------------+
 | When users attempt to use Kerberos and specify a principal or user name   |
 | without specifying what administrative Kerberos realm that principal      |
 | belongs to, the system appends the default realm.  The default realm may  |
 | also be used as the realm of a Kerberos service running on the local      |
 | machine.  Often, the default realm is the uppercase version of the local  |
 | DNS domain.                                                               |
 |                                                                           |
 | Default Kerberos version 5 realm:                                         |
 |                                                                           |
 | MYDOMAIN.COM________________________________________________________________ |
 |                                                                           |
 |                                  <Ok>                                     |
 |                                                                           |
 +---------------------------------------------------------------------------+
# specify the hostname
 +------------------+ Configuring Kerberos Authentication +------------------+
 | Enter the hostnames of Kerberos servers in the SRV.WORLD Kerberos         |
 | realm separated by spaces.                                                |
 |                                                                           |
 | Kerberos servers for your realm:                                          |
 |                                                                           |
 | dc1.mydomain.com____________________________________________________________ |
 |                                                                           |
 |                                  <Ok>                                     |
 |                                                                           |
 +---------------------------------------------------------------------------+

# specify the hostname
 +------------------+ Configuring Kerberos Authentication +------------------+
 | Enter the hostname of the administrative (password changing) server for   |
 | the SRV.WORLD Kerberos realm.                                             |
 |                                                                           |
 | Administrative server for your Kerberos realm:                            |
 |                                                                           |
 | dc1.mydomain.com____________________________________________________________ |
 |                                                                           |
 |                                  <Ok>                                     |
 |                                                                           |
 +---------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

After messing things up, how do I properly clean the mess on the server to start fresh with a new domain? And most importantly, how to start the Kerberos configuration wizard again?